# Save annotations into Data base

Tags: javascript, database, save, range

I need to save the annotations that other people do on the website. I need to save the selections of a text HTML in a database for retrieval later. Before users can view them whenever they want. I have used [rangy.deserializeSelection () and rangy.SerializeSelection ()](https://code.google.com/p/rangy/wiki/SerializerModule) but when reloading the page does not work.

I tried to create the range with the positions:

```
var srcObj = document.getElementById ("tam");
var rangeObj = document.createRange ();
rangeObj.selectNodeContents (srcObj);
var textNode = rangeObj.firstChild;
rangeObj.setStart (textNode, 1);
rangeObj.setEnd (textNode, 1000);
```

but neither worked,because it is not plain text has html brands.

Comment: no, im sorry. But you can try demo [http://rangy.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/serializer.html] and you can try to copy the serialized code and then deserializae it into another browser. This does not work.I try to save the serialized codes in the database, then I try to deserialize from the database but It does not work. I do not know how to save the selected text and I recovered the position of text with any browser later.

Comment: Ah, I see. Yes, a serialization generated in one browser probably won't work in another. Sorry.